# ServiceStack - IOC Disposal

Tags: servicestack, ioc-container, funq

I'm using ServiceStack's funq, I'm trying to get a hold on the place where the IOC gets disposed at the end of a request. Particularly for the entries with scope = ReuseScope.Request.

I'm looking at RestHandler's ProcessRequest method, which is the method that gets called directly by Asp.NET, and it ends like this:

```
(...)    
        if (doJsonp && !(response is CompressedResult))
                httpRes.WriteToResponse(httpReq, response, (callback + "(").ToUtf8Bytes(), ")".ToUtf8Bytes());
            else
                httpRes.WriteToResponse(httpReq, response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!EndpointHost.Config.WriteErrorsToResponse) throw;
            HandleException(httpReq, httpRes, operationName, ex);
        }
    }
```

I see no reference to a Funq disposal. What am I missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Container Scope is the same as Singleton Scope and only gets disposed when the [AppHost is disposed](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ec93fa32938ceca79091742f67eac29b60cdd013/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L834).

RequestScoped resources are disposed in [ServiceStackHost.OnEndRequest()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ec93fa32938ceca79091742f67eac29b60cdd013/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.cs#L627)

You can override `AppHost.Release(object instance)` in your AppHost to get notified when ServiceStack releases resources.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It was ReuseScope.Request

I am looking for the call. Where is this triggered?

Thanks

Comment: Updated answer, in ServiceStackHost.OnEndRequest()

Comment: @Blitzkrieg No that shouldn't be possible, the call usually originates from the **EndRequest()** extension method which is called from every known exit point.